# Have Make build a variable number of sub-directories

Tags: makefile

In my project, I have a subfolder called `samples`, in which there are a number of directories, one for each sample.

I'd like make to build and all of the samples via rules, without maintaining a list of them.

So far, I have this:

```
test-samples: $(wildcard samples/**/Cargo.toml)

samples/%/Cargo.toml : samples/%/context.toml flowc
    @echo ""
    @echo "------- Compiling and Generating code from flow: $< ----"
    ./target/debug/flowc $<

samples/%/target : samples/%/Cargo.toml
    @echo "------- Compiling and Running generated code: $< ----"
    @cargo run --quiet --manifest-path $<
```

If the `Cargo.toml` file and `target` directories already exist - then the dependencies work and they are re-generated.

But I can't get the rules to run if the `Cargo.toml` file does not yet exist (first time), or the `target` directory doesn't yet exist.

Comment: Hi, I have a solution for that in my `GNU make` templates here, there is a tutorial: https://github.com/igagis/prorab/blob/master/wiki/TutorialBasicConcepts.md

Answer (score 0):

I think this maybe a solution using path substitution.

Let me know what you think:

```
sample_flows := $(patsubst samples/%,samples/%/target,$(wildcard samples/*))

test-samples: $(sample_flows)

samples/%/Cargo.toml : samples/%/context.toml ./target/debug/flowc
    @echo ""
    @echo "------- Compiling and Generating code from flow: $< ----"
    ./target/debug/flowc $<

samples/%/target : samples/%/Cargo.toml
    @echo "------- Compiling and Running generated code: $< ----"
    @cargo run --quiet --manifest-path $<
```

Comment: I suggest `sample_flows := $(addsuffix /target,$(wildcard samples/*))', and add the command `mkdir -p $@` to the second rule.

Comment: addsuffix sounds more like what I'm trying to do semantically, so OK. Cargo run will make the folder when it runs.